# I cant get my calculations print in the label

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the values to calculate the profit and print out the calculated numbers in a label, but it isn't printing it out in the label. When I hover over "outputValue" after the app crashed it has the calculated value stored in it, but for some reason it doesn't print out in the label and gives me the error

> Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?'

at line  `ProfitLabel.text = (outputValue)`  in `insertNewItems()`. Is there any way to fix this?

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    @IBOutlet weak var OrderNumberLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var CostLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfitLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var TotalLabel: RoundedLabel2!

    @IBOutlet weak var itemTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var saleTextField: UITextField!

        var items: [ItemRow] = []

    struct ItemRow: Codable
        {
          var first: String
          var second: String
          var third: String
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            load()
//            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        }


    func save(){
        if let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedItems")
        }

    }

    func load(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "SavedItems") {
            items = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([ItemRow].self, from: data)


        }

    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        insertNewItems()
        save()


    }




        func insertNewItems() {


            let newVideoRow = ItemRow(first: itemTextField.text!, second: priceTextField.text!, third: saleTextField.text!)
            items.append(newVideoRow)



            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            let priceValue = Double(priceTextField.text!)
            let saleValue = Double(saleTextField.text!)

            if priceValue != nil && saleValue != nil {

                let outputValue = Double (saleValue! - priceValue!)

                ProfitLabel.text = (outputValue)
            }


            itemTextField.text = ""
            priceTextField.text = ""
            saleTextField.text = ""

            view.endEditing(true)
        }

    }





    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

             let ItemTitle = items[indexPath.row]

               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell
               cell.itemLabel.text = ItemTitle.first
               cell.priceLabel.text = ItemTitle.second
               cell.saleLabel.text = ItemTitle.third
               return cell
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == .delete {
                items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
                save()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: First check whether you are getting `outputValue ` or not .

Comment: after i ran it the log said priceValue Double? 1
saleValue Double? 3
outputValue Double 2 . its getting the value but wont print

Comment: What is RoundedLabel2, what UI component is it based on?

Comment: It rounds out the label for style

Comment: Not sure what that means but it is only a visual difference compared to a standard label and content is the same?

Comment: Yeah it’s all visual

Answer (score 1):

Simply disconnect you ProfitLabel and reconnect the outlet.
Also try convert output value to string like this:

```
ProfitLabel.text = "\(output)"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear: You are going to assign a Double to a text property which is impossible.

There is an easy solution

```
ProfitLabel.text = String(outputValue)
```

However your code is cumbersome and *objective-c-ish*, the recommended Swift syntax is

```
if let priceValue = Double(priceTextField.text!),
   let saleValue = Double(saleTextField.text!) {
        ProfitLabel.text = String(saleValue - priceValue)
}
```

If the code still crashes then the text field `ProfitLabel` is not connected in Interface Builder.

Side notes:

- Please name variables according to the naming convention with starting lowercase letter.
- Delete `beginUpdates/endUpdates`. Both lines have no effect.

Comment: dont i need begin and end updates for the table view?

Comment: Yes, you don't need it for a single insert/delete/move operation.

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value is all i get

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. You have to connect the text field to the `ProfitLabel` IBOutlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: i did, i checked and double checked and all the outlets are good

Comment: Please check again. The code must not crash if all outlets are connected properly.

Comment: is it because the table view and text fields are in a different view controller then the label i want it to print out on?, i have two view controllers but there both in the same view controller class

Comment: Yes this is most likely the reason.

Comment: how do i fix that? is there any way to get it to print in the label?

Comment: Actually that's another question and depends on the specific design.

Comment: Its just two view controllers, one that shows the profit and the other one you add how much the item costs and how much it was sold for then it saves it in a table view

Answer (score 0):

```
ProfitLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", outputValue) as String
```

it will round off up to 2 decimal places convert double into the string

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: can u try to print the outputValue just before assigning into the ProfitLabel and check what u are getting

Comment: i did 1 - 3 and outputValue printed 2.0 then crashed

Answer (score 0):

```swift
if priceValue != nil && saleValue != nil {
    let profit = Double(saleValue)! - Double(priceValue)!
    ProfitLabel.text = profit
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'

Comment: write the following line like this when calculating profit:    let profit = Double(saleValue!) - Double(priceValue!)

Comment: Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Double'

Answer (score 0):

You are force unwrapping the values. Replace following code

```swift
let priceValue = Double(priceTextField.text!)
            let saleValue = Double(salesTextField.text!)
if priceValue != nil && saleValue != nil {

                let outputValue = Double (saleValue! - priceValue!)

                ProfitLabel.text = (outputValue)
            }
```

> With

```swift
if let price = Double(priceTextField.text ?? ""), let sale = Double(salesTextField.text ?? "") {
    let outputValue = price - sale
    ProfitLabel.text = String(outputValue)
} else {
    print("Getting nil for \(priceTextField.text) or \(salesTextField.text)")
}
```

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Does it prints `Final output value` ?

Comment: I have updated the line `String(format: "%.2f", outputValue)` , did you tried that ?

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double', build failed

Comment: Try now, if you still getting error in appending value to label, there must be issue with your `profitLabel`.

Comment: Final output value 2.0
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional

Comment: Might be issue with label.Goto `connections inspector` in storyboard , check any warning or extra outlets added.if everything looks good and still crashing , Delete that label completely from code and storyboard and add a new one.

Comment: it doesnt crash now after doing that, but it doesnt print in the label

Comment: after `ProfitLabel.text = String(outputValue)`  add `print (ProfitLabel.text)`

Comment: now its saying "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Double' to 'nil' always returns true"

Comment: remove `if outputValue != nil {} eslse {}` and add `ProfitLabel.text = String(outputValue)`

Comment: so delete the if statement?, can u update code so im not doing it wrong

Comment: i just get Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value again

Comment: okay just try `ProfitLabel.text = "Update this in label"` to make sure the label was working fine.

Comment: @user12494754 If the code in this answer doesn’t work then the issue is elsewhere